# Where should i put my Admin control panel?

Tags: php, mysql, security, admin

I'm building a community site using PHP/MySQL, I was thinking of just letting admins login where normal users log in, and then present them with a "Admin Control Panel" link. So that the control panel platform is hosted on the same site. Is this secure? Should there be a different "gateway" for admins instead i.e. http://admin.example.com? Or should i host the Control Panel on an entirely different domain?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use a directory with limited access using .htaccess.

If the user-account of an admin will be hacked, his access to the ACP is still secure.

Comment: This is simple yet practical, I hadn't thought about this one.

Answer (score 3):

Having admins and normal users log in using the same form is not necessarily less secure, depending your other security measures. Some CMS systems, such as Drupal, use that model.

You're better off focusing energy on other security concerns, rather than [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Do you limit admin logins to certain IP addresses? Do you block users after a number of unsuccessful login attempts? Do you encourage/force strong passwords? Etc.

Comment: Forcing https for admin logins also isn't a bad idea (when possible)

Comment: Agreed! Forcing https for **all admin pages** isn't a bad idea either.

Answer (score 1):

I log in everyone with a correct username/password. But I also have an additional column in my users table for admins with (hard to guess) values for "yes" and "no". If a user logs in, I'm also checking this column, and if the value is "yes" I check another table for admin privileges.

But the admin panel itself is located in a regular folder, such as: /admin. As you would expect.